# Using Authorize.net ARB subscription created but card not charged

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

```
<input type="hidden" name="startDate" value='<?php echo $date_up; ?>'>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value='9.95'>
<input type="hidden" name="totalOccurrences" value='9999'>
<input type="hidden" name="length" value='1'>
<input type="hidden" name="unit" value='months'>
<input type="hidden" name="trialOccurrences" value='0'>
<input type="hidden" name="trialAmount" value='0'>
```

Where $date_up == Tomorrow;
It is creating the subscription but is not charging it. I am presuming it is going to charge next month and it is for some reason giving it a trial? Should I remove trial from the submission altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at this for days but after posting this I just imagined I was someone else and figured it out.  The date was a month out because of how I rearranged it with php:
$date_up = date('Y-m-d', $date_up);
I had used "h" instead of "m" or something like this and it made the subscription start a month in advance.

If you're having this problem in the future whoever you are - go check your authorize.net subscription creation date and make sure that you didn't set it too far out like i did expecting it to charge the next day.